# Can we duplicate a `Drawing` component in GitBook?

Tags: gitbook

I thought I could just copy a `Drawing` component and paste it into another page to duplicate it, but I was wrong. When I edited the pasted drawing and returned back to my original one, I was shocked to find out that it had been updated too.

So I found out painfully that I didn't make a duplicate drawing afterall, instead I made a "**reference**" to the original one, which definitely was not what I wanted.

So is it possible to duplicate a `Drawing` in GitBook, instead of drawing from scratch each time?

Answer (score 0):

Open two tabs in browser with drawing editor. Select all items in drawing mode in one tab, 'Copy to clipboard as SVG' and paste into second tab drawing editor.